# Loop though IList, but with for loop, not for each

Tags: c#, for-loop

I have a IList of objects.
They are of type NHibernate.Examples.QuickStart.User.
There is also an EmailAddress public string property.

Now I can loop through that list with a for each loop.
Is it possible to loop through a Ilist with a simple for loop?
Because simply treating the IList as an array doesn't seem to work...

```
System.Collections.IList results = crit.List();

foreach (NHibernate.Examples.QuickStart.User i in results)
{
    Console.WriteLine(i.EmailAddress);
}

for (int i = 0; i < results.Count; ++i)
{
    Console.WriteLine(results[i].EmailAddress); // Not Working
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since you are using a non-Generic IList, you are required to cast the value:

```
for (int i = 0; i < results.Count; ++i)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(((NHibernate.Examples.QuickStart.User)results[i]).EmailAddress); // Not Working
    }
```

Alternatively, you could make your IList the Generic version by changing the 1st line to:

`System.Collections.IList<NHibernate.Examples.QuickStart.User> results = crit.List();`

Note that for this solution, you would have to change the crit.List() function to return this type.

Answer (score 2):

```
for (int i = 0; i < results.Count; ++i)
{
    Console.WriteLine((NHibernate.Examples.QuickStart.User)results[i]).EmailAddress); // Not Working
}
```

Remember to cast the element type properly, since the `IList` indexer returns a simple `object`.

Answer (score 2):

You are using a basic IList, which store objects as type `Object`. If you use a `foreach`, type casting is done for you automatically. But if you use an indexer as in `for (i = 0; i<count...` , it is not.

Try this, see if it works:

```
for (int i = 0; i < results.Count; ++i)
{
    var result = (NHibernate.Examples.QuickStart.User)results[i];
    Console.WriteLine(result.EmailAddress); // Not Working
}
```

...

Comment: You mean: `result.EmailAddress`